# ASP.NET MVC: Returning large amounts of data from FileResult

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, controller, out-of-memory

I have a file browser application in MVC4 that allows you to download a selected file from a controller.

Currently, the FileResult returns the Stream of the file, along with the other response headers. While this works fine for smaller files, files that are larger generate an OutOfMemoryException.

What I'd like to do is transmit the file from the controller, without buffering in memory in a fashion similiar to HttpReponse.TransmitFile in WebForms.

How can this be accomplished?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can disable the response buffer before you return the file result.

```
Response.BufferOutput = false;
return File(fileStream, contentType);
```

Comment: This is the only (clean) solution that worked for me, thanks!

Comment: Note that for really large files (2GB+) you also need to set `HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead` to prevent `Cannot write more bytes to the buffer than the configured maximum buffer size: 2147483647.` exception.

Comment: Thank you. It works in my case for files larger than 170 MB.

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can by using Web Api in order to stream the file, take a look at this article [Dealing with large files in ASP.NET Web API](http://www.strathweb.com/2012/09/dealing-with-large-files-in-asp-net-web-api/)

Comment: Question is about MVC, not Web API

Answer (score 0):

Additionaly to the above link describing configuration, you may use TransmitFile to "stream" files. However, TransmitFile has some backwards on some http clients.

This is my code to "stream" files to client, as an alternative for TransmitFile. Note that I've have a config constant to rollback with WriteFile (which have the same OutOfMemory issue as yours) :

```
    private void RenderContent(string contentType,string fileName, bool inline);
```

method code :

```
FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(fileName);

Response.ClearHeaders();
Response.ClearContent();

Response.ContentType = contentType;
Response.CacheControl = "No-cache";
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(System.Web.HttpCacheability.NoCache);
Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", fi.Length.ToString());
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", (inline ? "inline" : "attachment") + "; filename=\"" + fi.Name + "\"");

if (cAppInfos.Constant["FallBackToWriteFile"] != null && cAppInfos.Constant["FallBackToWriteFile"] == "true")
{
    Response.WriteFile(fileName);
}
else
{
    int chunkSize = 8192;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[chunkSize];
    int offset = 0;
    int read = 0;
    using (FileStream fs = File.Open(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
    {
        while ((read = fs.Read(buffer, offset, chunkSize)) > 0)
        {
            if (!Response.IsClientConnected)
                break;

            Response.OutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, read);
            Response.Flush();
        }
    }
}
```

I used this code to avoid some problems in streaming pdf files to old acrobat reader plugin. For the inline parameter, you may use "false".

Additionaly, you may use try/catch around this code, as any of Response.IsClientConnecter/Write/Flush can throw exceptions if client disconnect.

However, I'm not using MVC, and I'm not sure this is acceptable for this techno, as if you have not used TransmitFile, you may be stuck with the same issue with this code.
If you are trying to embedd files into web pages element (as base64 maybe ?) this is not the solution.

Let me know more information about your requirements, if you need others ways to achieve your goals.

Comment: Additionaly, the choice to present the result as "stream files" may not be relevant in the controller, and may be moved in the presentation, where you get access to the Response object.

Controller may just ask the presentation layer to stream the... filestream/filename ?

Comment: In response to your "Controller may just ask the presentation layer to stream the..." comment, As it would have to serve the stream in the same fashion, would this just introduce the same issue at a different location?

Comment: I'm not an MVC expert, but I suggest you to move the issue in a place where you can resolve it (ie : a place with access to the Response object)