# How to play large file 500Мb in ASP.NET MVC HTML audio player?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html5-audio

I tried these ways to solve this problem.

1. Return path to the file;

   ```
   [HttpGet]
   public ActionResult GetTrackById(Guid id)
   {
      string fileNameOnServer = GetFile(id);
      return  File(fileNameOnServer , Response.ContentType);
   }
   ```
2. Return byte array

   ```
   [HttpGet]
   public ActionResult GetTrackById(Guid id)
   {
      byte[] bufferToSend = GetFile(id);
      return  File(bufferToSend, Response.ContentType);
   }
   ```

   In this situation i get OutOfMemoryException.
3. Return stream

   ```
   [HttpGet]
   public ActionResult GetTrackById(Guid id)
   {
      Stream stream = GetFile(id);
      return  File(stream , Response.ContentType);
   }
   ```

So the question is, how to play audio file by parts, and make audio player to send range requests for file to play and load. I didn't find anything helpful on Google.

Comment: Put it on SoundCloud and let them deal with it. This is not a trivial problem to code on your own I'm afraid.

Comment: Before you dive into audio details and all that - you may read something like
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12710013/asp-net-mvc-returning-large-amounts-of-data-from-fileresult
to actually send data partially.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried making the response stream asynchronously? These links might be helpful ...

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/asynchronous-videos-live-streaming-with-asp-net-web-apis-2-0/

http://www.tugberkugurlu.com/archive/efficiently-streaming-large-http-responses-with-httpclient

Comment: Yes it works, i will put my code later to show to another people how do it works, thank you.

Comment: Most welcome! :)