# Download from FTP and serve result using streams

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

In my Asp.Net MVC application I want to implement a method that allows me to download files stored on an FTP. I'd like to compete the following code to use streams and avoid downloading the entire file first and then serving them as FileResult

```
   public FileResult getBigFileFromFTP()
    {
        FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://ftp-location.com/test/bigfile.zip");

        request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile;
         
        request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("ftpuser", "ftppwd");

        FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

        Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
        
        //Missing code... I would like to serve the file during FTP download


           

    }
```

Comment: A `FileResult` can work with a `Stream` as well. You can write `return File(responseStream);` in your action

Comment: Yes, but if I write some like:

`return File(responseStream, "application/x-zip-compressed", "bigfile.zip");`

My user will have to wait for the entire download from the FTP server before starting his HTTP download. 

Is there a way to serve the stream **during** FTP download?

Comment: ASP.NET MVC buffers output by default before sending it to the client to ensure the client receives a complete HTML page. You can disable buffering with `Response.BufferOutput = false;`. Check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12710013/asp-net-mvc-returning-large-amounts-of-data-from-fileresult)

Comment: Very simple, great solution. It was exactly what I was looking for. Thank-you a lot!!! :-))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a `FileResult` from a stream. By default ASP.NET Core buffers a response before sending it to the browser. This can be a problem with big files. To avoid this you need to disable buffering.

Try using :

```
Response.BufferOutput = false;
return File(responseStream);
```